# How to count similar elements in list for an inventory implementation

Tags: python

I would like it to print each element of a list in the format

```
 > Item(int)
```

with item being the list element and int being the amount of the item

```
from collections import Counter

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = ["wood","wood","flint","steel"]

    def print_inv(self):
        print(" -- Inventory -- ")
        for item in self.inventory:
            print(" > " + str(item) + "(" + str(self.inventory.count(item)) + ")")

Player().print_inv()
```

this is the code I have tried using .count() that was closest to my needs but when it prints wood it prints twice due to the for loop. I can't find another way around.

Comment: I don't think you need to walk over `self.inventory` to count the items. Just print `Counter(self.inventory)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `Counter`. Use it to first count the items, and then print the result (preferably using f-string):

```py
from collections import Counter

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = ["wood","wood","flint","steel"]

    def print_inv(self):
        print(" -- Inventory -- ")
        for item, quantity in Counter(self.inventory).items():
            print(f" > {item}({quantity})")

Player().print_inv()
```

The code above will give you the following result:

```
 -- Inventory -- 
 > wood(2)
 > flint(1)
 > steel(1)
```

Comment: I suggest making `self.inventory` an instance of `Counter`, if the goal is to implement inventory for a `Player` class without hidden conditions.  Preserving item order and recalculating totals on print doesn't make a lot of sense to me.